# What is the use of g tag?

Tags: svg

I am new to `svg`, as far as I saw everywhere they using `svg` elements within `g` **tag**, is there any particular reason for using `svg` elements within `g` tag other than applying transformation for whole set of elements?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's a pretty important and useful reason.  But other reasons you might do it are so you can:

- apply the same styling (eg. fill="blue") to a set of elements,
- reference to the group of objects from a `use`.

Not to mention the simple organisational reasons.

Answer (score 17):

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/g-element.html says:

> The `<g>` element is used to group SVG shapes together. Once grouped you can transform the whole group of shapes as if it was a single shape. This is an advantage compared to a nested `<svg>` element which cannot be the target of transformation by itself.